# Separate column data with a comma to two columns for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api

The data set I pulled from an API return looks like this:

```
([['Date', 'Value']],
 [[['2019-08-31', 445000.0],
   ['2019-07-31', 450000.0],
   ['2019-06-30', 450000.0]]])
```

I'm trying to create a DataFrame with two columns from the data: 
Date & Value

Here's what I've tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(city_data, index =['a', 'b'], columns =['Names'] . 
    ['Names1'])
```

```
city_data[['Date','Value']] = 
    city_data['Date'].str.split(',',expand=True)
    city_data
```

```
city_data.append({"header": column_value, 
                    "Value": date_value})
    city_data = pd.DataFrame()
```

This code was used to create the dataset. I pulled the lists from the API return:

```
column_value = data["dataset"]["column_names"]
    date_value = data["dataset"]["data"]

    city_data = ([column_value], [date_value])
    city_data
```

Instead of creating a dataframe with two columns from the data, in most cases I get the "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it what you are looking for:

`d = ([['Date', 'Value']],
 [[['2019-08-31', 445000.0],
   ['2019-07-31', 450000.0],
   ['2019-06-30', 450000.0]]])`

`pd.DataFrame(d[1][0], columns=d[0][0])`

return:

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly but there are 50 rows